# How to use showDialog() to show an untouchable toast message in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have to create a custom Toast for my app, and I tried using the same method that I used for a custom dialogue, like this.

```
void openToast(context, text) {
  showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext ctx) => IgnorePointer(
            child: LToast(
              text: text,
            ),
          ),
      barrierDismissible: false,
  );
}
```

And the widget `LToast` is a Text wrapped in a `Container` which is the child of a `Material` whose color is set to `transparent`. The toast gets correctly showed over the page but if `barrierDismissible` is `true` I touch, the toast closes but the event doesn't register on the page below, and If I turn off barrierDismissible the widget simply doesn't close on touch and it's impossible to close (As it's intended to work). I even tried with an IgnorePointer widget but nothing changes.
So I don't think showDialog is the right choice.
To sum it up I'm looking to create a toast that Open and closes with an animation, so shouldn't just close on touching (hence barrierDismissible should be false) and that is invisible to touch. Is it possible?

I prefer not to use Toast package because as far as I know isn't customizable in color and fontsize as well as animations. Are there better solutions?

Answer (score 1):

use future delayed function to auto dismiss the dialog after few seconds. it acts as timer  and pop your dialog.

something like this:

```
void showToast(context) {
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
        Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
      });
      return IgnorePointer(
        child: customToastIcon,
      );
    },
    barrierDismissible: false,
  );
}
```

if you need to customize toast message, you can do that with this [plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/bot_toast).

hope this helps you!!